# After saving ASPX page the URL's are broken. How can I save the full URL for images and CSS?

Tags: c#, dynamic, path

I have requirements to save an ASPX page to an HTML file for further use.   The code below works perfectly and saves all the dynamic content on the page without issue.  Where i ran into a problem is the header image link and the link to the CSS.  Both are a partial path which produces a broken link.  Is there a way I can have the page load/save using the full path to those items?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
string myPageHTML = null;
Statement stmtPage = new Statement();

Server.Execute("Statement.aspx", sw);

myPageHTML = sw.ToString();
```

Just be a little more clear on the results I'm seeing is after saving there is no domain and its the relative path without the domain.  The images and CSS are hosted on the site so all I need is for the full path to save.

Comment: Those would be relative paths wherever the site is hosted (or some CDN, but keep it simple for now). And you'd need to change the links to your locally downloaded resources. So, `www.something.com/static/` would become 'c:\\SomethingLocal\\static`

Comment: It's saving like /static/image.jpg instead of www.example.com/static/image.jpg .. I'm trying to save the full URL to the hosted image and CSS.

Comment: Then you just need to replace src="/static.." tags to src=/http:/url.com/static" with a simple string replace.

Comment: Take a look at this http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/258990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add a `<base>` tag to your HTML? See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

> The HTML `<base>` element specifies the base URL to use for all relative
>   URLs contained within a document.There is maximum one `<base>` element
>   in a document.

Comment: I cannot up your answer because of my score but it was perfect!  I implemented the base tag and it worked perfectly.  The only problem I see for others would be if you had multiple domains being used.  For my purposes we only are using one and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44949/generating-the-html-code-of-a-server-page-in-the-itemadded-event-receiver).

```
System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url)
```

Comment: Implementing webclient() from what I found is a big pain when you have dynamic content and code that uses session variables from previous pages etc.  That's why I avoided it by using a Server.Execute.  I don't see a way for me to go that route.